# Dolphin and samba 1 share windows

Tags: kde, samba

it'possible from dolphin enter in a windows share that use smb v1.0?

From kde dolphin i can't access,connection timeout but if i visit from win10 with smbv1 enable, i can enter in the folder!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, quite possible. You have to write this under `[global]` section of your `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

```
client min protocol = NT1
```

It sets the minimum supported version for client (your device) to SMBv1. For all possible versions, see [this](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#CLIENTMAXPROTOCOL). Default version is SMBv2.02
Edit: Answered in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265923/configuring-20-04-samba-for-smbv1#1265990)